# What does char[n][100] mean?

Tags: c

My professor gave me a C file and I can't really understand it well.
It's a program that reads from a text file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main(){
    int n,m;
    char start[30],end[30];
    FILE *a;
    a=fopen("test.txt","r");
    fscanf(a,"%s",&start);
    fscanf(a,"%s",&end);
    fscanf(a,"%d",&m);
    fscanf(a,"%d",&n);
    printf("\n%s\n%s\n%d\n%d",start,end,m,n);
    char word[n][30];
    int i=0;
    while(!feof(a)){
        fscanf(a,"%s",&word[i]);
        i++;

    }

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("\n%s",word[i]);
    fclose (a);

}
```

here's the text file:

```
blah alooa
7 4
hey
boom
stackoverflow
testing
```

So, I'm wondering what does this `char word[n][30]` mean? why does it have `[n]`?

Comment: It's a "variable length array", a C99 feature.

Comment: It's an array of `n` arrays of `100` characters.

Comment: On an unrelated note, please read [Why is “while (!feof(file))” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feoffile-always-wrong) You might want to forward the link to your professor.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: Why not ask your professor what it means?

Comment: Lundin, I don't have a class for the next 2 weeks, that's why.

Comment: If your C book doesn't cover what a VLA (variable length array) is, it is time you got a book written in the current millennium (and written to take into account the changes made by C99, and preferably C11 too, though the changes in C11 are small by comparison with those in C99).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Can you please recommend any good book ? I know many, but I want your recommendation.

Comment: See [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  I think K N King "C Programming: A Modern Approach (2nd Edn)" is a good choice.  It doesn't cover C11 per se, but does cover C99.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, I'm wondering what does this char word[n][30] mean?

Technically, it is a 2 dimensional VLA of characters. It is used in this program to store "n" words, where each word can be of max 30 characters length.

> why does it have [n]?

It's a variable used to store the number of words in the file.

Looking at your program, probably, you have to enter 8 as the value of `n`.

Answer (score -1):

Well n is the number if word you have and it is readed from the file.
It’s like you have some parameters stored within your file in the first lines